# Passing data from ASP.MVC controller to Angular controller Typescript

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, typescript

I have an app that will be started from external app possibly with a parameter (only one) coming with url. I have a following Action inside my MVC Home Controller:

```
    public JsonResult LoadParam()
    {
        var query = Request.Url.Query.ToString();
        string id = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(query).Get(0);
        return Json(id);
    }
```

My problem is how do I call this from angular code? Normally I would use Get, but then I am passing "Home/LoadParam" url and it does not make any sense. I tried passing $location.url(), but then I won't hit LoadParam() action since my single page app stands on Home/Index URL. Not to mention that I couldn't make $location to get me any result (always getting an empty string). 
So, to sum up - my question is how do I call this action from angualr code to retrieve the value of parameter when the app is open?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `$location` service to get the query parameters on the client side rather than get it from the server side.

```
//Access via property
var id = location.search().id;
//Access as array
var id = location.search()[0];
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location

Comment: Yes, but I really don't know what is the value of the parameter in the URL so clearly I cannot pass it to the MVC controller. This is exactly what I want to get FROM the LoadParam Action.

Comment: Didn't understand what you were asking for, to get the query parameter passed to the page please see my latest update